# Inserting an element in an ordered list in a Django model

Tags: python, sql, django

i'm trying to figure out how to create an ordered list of elements in a Django model.

I'm trying to extend the User model to add a rank (like military rank) to a user. I would like to sort/filter the users per rank, and I would like to store an svg graphical representation of a rank. I would like to use the rank level to establish a hierarchy amongst users, so the rank level must be unique. Lastly, I would like to be able to insert or delete a rank if change arise in the future.

To achieve this, I created a table for the ranks like so:

```py
class Rank(Models.model):
    rank = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    level = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField()
```

What I would like is the ability for the level field to update itself if I insert a new rank between 2 already existing ranks.

For example, let's say I create the following ranks:

id [pk] | rank | level | image

1 | soldier | 1 | soldier.svg

2 | sergent | 2 | sergent.svg

I then want to insert "corporal" at level 2 so that the table would look like:

id [pk] | rank | level | image

1 | soldier | 1 | soldier.svg

3 | corporal | 2 | corporal.svg

2 | sergent | 3 | sergent.svg

Here, by inserting the `corporal` entry at level `2` the `sergent` level automatically renumbered itself to `3`. If I delete the `soldier` entry, I would then like the table to look like so:

id [pk] | rank | level | image

3 | corporal | 1 | corporal.svg

2 | sergent | 2 | sergent.svg

where both `corporal` and `sergent` levels renumbering themselves to `1` and `2`.

I don't mind having to specify the level of a new rank, but I would like the higher ranks to re-order themselves automatically on insertion or deletion. I don't think having the level being a primary key (PK) is a good idea, since I don't necessarily want the relation with the user to change if I update that table. I don't expect that table to grow much, so the operation does not have to be very optimal.

The answer might be very simple or obvious, but I'm very new to Django/python/databases development. I've read the django documentation and I've searched on google and on this site for an answer but I could get my finger on what I am looking for.

Kind regards!

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you need these ranks in your database?  You might be better off using an enum depending on how this model is used.

Comment: also, `blank=False` is the default, so no need to add that.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica I want the ranks to be editable by the web app's end user, as they (although rarely) may change. As well, I'm trying to build a platform that would suit different military elements that has different ranks (navy, army, air command, etc). I don't really know how to use an enum to store that info and keep it editable.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica Also thanks for that blank=false cue, I'll edit my code!

Comment: In that case you are correct.  It isn't a good idea to use enums for user-defined data.